# python AttributeError 'dict' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-database

I get following error:

```
AttributeError at /filterrule/createresultset/
'dict' object has no attribute 'filter_query_json'
```

Here's the code:

```
from django.db import connections

def fetch_filter_rule_sql_from_ui_db(filter_rule_id):
    with connections['frontend'].cursor() as cursor:
        query = "SELECT id, filter_query_json FROM dmf_filter_rules WHERE id=%s LIMIT 1"
        cursor.execute(query, [filter_rule_id])
        filter_rule_sql_json = dictfetchall(cursor)[0].filter_query_json
        # filter_rule_sql_json = dictfetchall(cursor)[0][filter_query_json]
        return filter_rule_sql_json

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

The output to `dictfetchall(cursor)[0]` is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "filter_query_json": "{\"request_id\":\"341\",\"match_status\":\"1\",\"verdict\":\"Non Match\",\"matched\":\"s_vs_r_image_class_match\"}"
}
```

Object looks fine to me and I confirmed the `filter_query_json` attribute too.

What is missing?

Comment: @roganjosh i meant inside the output object : `filter_query_json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get the straight value if the object is the built-in `dict` type. To fix this, the solution can be

```
filter_rule_sql_json = dictfetchall(cursor)[0].get('filter_query_json')
```

If your key `filter_query_json` does not exist, the method `.get(key)` would return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

change your line to `filter_rule_sql_json = dictfetchall(cursor)[0]['filter_query_json']`

athough I would recommend using django's database api rather than writing raw sql queries